# Have wordpress installed on a subdirectory, want to import posts to root (homepage)

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I know my way around Wordpress coding, but my problem comes in with trying to import posts outside of the wordpress directory (one level down).

I just want to get say the 5 most current posts.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just access the database directly via PHP?

```
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("your_wordpress_database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `post_date` DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($post = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $post['post_title'] , "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Great idea... I actually thought of that, but was wondering if there was some way to do it just through perhaps importing some critical wordpress libraries.   Thanks, this is what I will do.

Comment: You're welcome, and here's a diagram of the WordPress database structure that should come in handy: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

(pssst, you should click that little green checkmark next to my answer :D)